# Python Pandas Delete and Log an Error Line in CSV

Tags: python, pandas

How to delete an error bad line in file.csv?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r"G:\file.csv", delimiter=',', error_bad_lines=False)
print(df.head())
```

My file is like this

```
column1, column2, column3
test, test, test
test2, test2, test2, te,st2
test3, test3, test3
te,st4, test4, te,st4, test4
```

**I want to delete this line from file.csv and record to error.txt**

```
test2, test2, test2, te,st2
te,st4, test4, te,st4, test4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it without pandas.

```
import csv
error_liens=[]
good_lines=[]
with open(r'D:\test.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    #if the first line is header
    header=0
    for row in reader:
        if header==0:
            header=1
            error_liens.append(",".join(row))
            good_lines.append(",".join(row))
            continue
        #checking if number of columns is not equal to 3 (bad lines)
        if len(row)!=3:
            error_liens.append(",".join(row))
        else:
            good_lines.append(",".join(row))
            
#write the error list to error file
f = open("error.csv", "w")
f.write("\n".join(error_liens))
f.close()


#write the good_lines list to correct lines file
f = open("good.csv", "w")
f.write("\n".join(good_lines))
f.close()
```

not sure if you can get a separate bad lines files using pandas.

Comment: thank you, i get error 
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 1455: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: replace `with open(r'D:\test.csv', 'r') as file:`
with `with open(r'D:\test.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:`
for encoding issue

Comment: hi @Amit, i use windows, get error `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 49470-49474: character maps to <undefined>` in this line `--> 22 f.write("\n".join(error_liens))`

Comment: try this `f=open("error.csv","w",encoding="utf-8")` while opening the file before `f.write()` for both the files.